# Codepoint from Unicode Character?

Tags: c++, unicode

This question has been asked before but it's solution is dependent on the Microsoft Foundation Class which I don't want to rely on.  Basically what I wan to do is convert a Unicode character into a it's equivalent codepoint.

The below was the solution using MFC.  Is there a way of doing this without using afxwin.h ?

```
#include <afxwin.h>

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    TCHAR   myString[50] = _T("عربى");
    int stringLength = _tcslen(myString); // <----- edit here

    for(int i=0;i<stringLength;i++)
    {
       unsigned int number =myString[i];
       cout<<number<<endl;
    }
}
Output:

1593
1585
1576
1609
```

Comment: If you really want to be thorough you'll need surrogate-pair support.

Comment: Are you compiling your project as UNICODE or ANSI?

Comment: `TCHAR` and `_tcslen()` are not part of MFC. They are part of the C runtime library. They are declared in `tchar.h`. But this code DOES NOT give you proper codepoints, as it is not taking UTF-16 surrogates into account (assuming `UNICODE` is defined so `TCHAR` maps to `wchar_t`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Update

If your compiler supports it, the easiest way to do this is probably to write your constant string as `U"عربى"`.  This gives you an array of `char32_t` characters whose code points are just their value converted with `static_cast<uint32_t>()`.  To print them in standard format, just prepend `U+` and print the hex value.

Try this on a C++14 compiler (I recommend saving the source file as utf-8).

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

int main()
{
  constexpr char32_t codepoints[] = U"عربى";
  constexpr size_t n = sizeof(codepoints)/sizeof(char32_t);

  cout.setf( cout.hex, cout.basefield );     // Output in hex
  cout.setf( cout.right, cout.adjustfield ); // Prepending
  cout.fill('0');                            // leading zeroes
  // Fixed: Don’t print the terminating U'\0'.
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < n && codepoints[i]; ++i )
    cout << "U+" << std::setw(4) << (unsigned long)codepoints[i] << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

## Conversions

The C++ STL has `<codecvt>` now, which can convert from utf-8 or utf-16 to ucs-32.  Example code (from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf16):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

void prepare_file()
{
  // UTF-16le data (if host system is little-endian)
  char16_t utf16le[4] ={0x007a, // latin small letter 'z' U+007a
                        0x6c34, // CJK ideograph "water"  U+6c34
                        0xd834, 0xdd0b}; // musical sign segno U+1d10b
  // store in a file
  std::ofstream fout("text.txt");
  fout.write( reinterpret_cast<char*>(utf16le), sizeof utf16le);
}

int main() 
{
  prepare_file(); // open as a byte stream
  std::wifstream fin("text.txt", std::ios::binary); 
  // apply facet
  fin.imbue(std::locale(fin.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::little_endian>));

  for (wchar_t c; fin.get(c); )
    std::cout << std::showbase << std::hex << c << '\n';
}
```

C11 and C++11 also have functions to convert between multibyte utf-8 and utf-16 and wide character strings (from here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/mbrtoc32).  The `mbstowcs()` function might be relevant, too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <uchar.h>
#include <assert.h>   

mbstate_t state;

int main(void)
{
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
  char *str = u8"z\u00df\u6c34\U0001F34C"; // or u8"zß水"   
  printf("Processing %zu bytes: [ ", strlen(str));
  for(char* p = str; *p; ++p)
    printf("%#x ", (unsigned char)*p); puts("]");

  char32_t c32;
  char *ptr = str, *end = str + strlen(str);
  int rc;

  while(rc = mbrtoc32(&c32, ptr, end - ptr, &state)) {
    printf("Next UTF-32 char: %#x obtained from ", c32);
    assert(rc != -3); // no surrogate pairs in UTF-32
    if(rc > 0) {
      printf("%d bytes [ ", rc);
      for(int n = 0; n < rc; ++n)
        printf("%#x ", (unsigned char)ptr[n]); puts("]");
      ptr += rc;
    }
  }
}
```

Although these examples use hex codes, C11 and C++11 support Unicode strings (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).  Since the Unicode in your sample above is utf-16le, the standard way to write it as a constant is `u"عربى"`.  You could also encode it as ucs-32 with `U"عربى"` and not have to do any surrogate-pair conversion.

Comment: Thanks, but my next question is can I insert a character I have extracted from a string in place of Hex codes you have entered above.  I want to convert characters directly into unicode codepoints.

Comment: Updated with instructions.  That makes this much simpler.

Comment: Thanks for your effort Lorehead.  Don't get me wrong here but I just need to say one thing.  I'm not the most advanced programmer in the world and looking at the syntax of the above it seems extremely complicated.  I will have to understand it before I use it.  I assume that only practice will get me through this.  Is your use of syntax very advanced?  I would think it is.  I'm just letting you know that I'm not a software engineer so it's going to be a struggle to understand your reply.

Comment: I’ve added some sample code with simple syntax, but unfortunately I’m on my phone and not able to test it. Caveat emptor.

Comment: For this to work you also have to save your source files as either UTF-16 (called ‘Unicode’ on Windows) or UTF-8 with BOM. Otherwise the interpretation of non-ASCII characters in your source file will be dependent on the system locale.

Comment: I recommend using utf-8 everywhere you can.  GCC accepts the `-finput-charset` command-line option or defaults to the current locale.   Visual Studio will try to autodetect, and identifies utf-8 correctly even without the BOM (but also has `/CODEPAGE`).  I don't know whether any compiler out there chokes on  the BOM, but you might try putting one in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the help Lorehead

Comment: Finally had a chance to test, and updated with a fix to not print the terminating nul.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, read unicode spec and take care unicode scalars,  surrogates and supplementary characters, extended grapheme cluster on your own.

Or you may use IBM ICU library which is included by most of today's OS.

If the issue is only MFC header files, you may define UNICODE, _UNICODE and include tchar.h.